# Is it worth continuing the old name votes? If so, how?

Tags: discussion, voting

Eleven months ago, [Naming our robot](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/naming-our-robot) proposed we name the robot visible in the main site background, on the lefthand side. A week later, [Naming our lady](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3201/naming-our-lady?lq=1) surfaced to give a title to its seemingly human companion.

However, after many names were contributed, no conclusive decision was made.
It seems like a waste; many interesting options were provided, and the idea is relatively on-topic, but we left the posts where they sat (as far as I know).

### Is it worth narrowing down the names, and if so, what is a fair way to do so?

Where would we display that information?

Answer (score 3):

Meh.  The whole thing is informal anyway; how often do people refer to these entities and need a name? So the askers of the questions should accept answers, and people should do with this whatever they like. :-)  If people want to write fiction (as one person has [already done](https://medium.com/universe-factory/the-lost-builder-355cf7de7ec6#.cjisn6xtp)), they can choose to be informed by the meta posts, or not.

I don't think there's anything official to do here.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the people who asked eventually forgot about the questions. If they're still around, my vote is that they accept the highest-voted answer and edit the question to clearly explain who won. If mods can do that, that would also work.

Also, we may need a new question to name the caveman on Meta (my suggestion would be Slartibrutefast).

Comment: Mods can't force acceptances.  But the whole thing is informal anyway; how often do people refer to these entities and need a name anyway?  So the askers of the questions should accept answers, and people should do with this whatever they like. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio That would be a good answer to this question as well

Answer (score -1):

Given that this is Worldbuilding, I suggest we construct a world, collectively, a la the Ainur in Lord of the Rings (Melkor and all). Then we let the world run forward for 100,000 years and on the anniversary of the creation, we count the names and take the most common one as the name of the lady and we give the robot the name of the first artificial being that the beings of our world construct.

That seems a fair and equitable approach that keeps with the spirit of the site.

Comment: Michael Butor rides again! A French writer who suggested science-fiction could be improved if there common (fictional or imaginary) places in its repertoire. I guess like a shared-world without the commercial franchise nonsense.

Comment: However, your suggestion is very creative. I've no idea if it would work, interesting to see what would come out of it.